# Why printf in main function doesn't work in flex on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I wrote a simple flex file `text.l`

```
%{
# include<stdio.h>
int key = 0;
int id = 0;
%}
%%
if|else|int|double|return { printf("KEY "); key++; }
[a-zA-Z]([0-9]|[a-zA-Z]|_)* { printf("ID "); id++; }
\n { printf("\n");}        
.          
%%
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  yylex();
  printf("key = %d, id = %d\n", key, id);
  yywrap();
  
}
int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
```

and I run the following commands in shell

```
flex text.l
gcc lex.yy.c
./a.out
```

I thought the program could print the values of `key` and `id` after terminating the process (using ctrl C), but the values didn't appear (`KEY`, `VALUE`s do appear). So only the `printf` in main function doesn't work.

I ran the same commands on windows, it did print the values after the process ended.

I've tried `fprintf(stdout, "test")` in main function, but it didn't work too.

Comment: I wonder if stdout is getting redirected somehow?  Perhaps `fprintf(stderr, "test\n");` would print something.